# Is this a data flow diagram?

Tags: charts, diagram

I am unsure on whether or not this (link) is a data flow chart or a flowchart? I am unsure because it seems too much like a block diagram to be a data flow diagram.

[image]

Answer (score -1, accepted):

The difference between a flow chart and a data flow diagram is that a data flow diagram provides a point where data is entered into the system and a point where data exits the system. The definition as provided by Wikipedia:

> A data flow diagram (DFD) is a graphical representation of the "flow"
>   of data through an information system, modeling its process aspects

A flow chart basically shows the flow of events not necessarily including the flow of data. It shows a process through which the program flows. A flow chart is defined by Wikipedia as:

> A flowchart is a type of diagram that represents an algorithm,
>   workflow or process, showing the steps as boxes of various kinds, and
>   their order by connecting them with arrows